# Find the total Number of Path of length L

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

find the number of the  path between two points on a grid where you can only move one unit up, down, left, or right? Is there a formula for this?.

Any shortest path from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ includes $m$ steps in the x axis and $n$ steps in the y axis. This is counted by the binomial coefficient $\binom{m+n}{m} = \binom{m+n}{n}$.

But what number about the total path exist of Length `L` in a grid  and We can revisit the cell ?

Comment: Do you want the number of paths (or rather walks) of a certain given length? Otherwise it is infinite.

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes walk , For a given Length `L` it's not infinite

Comment: Did you mention $L$ before (or edit in after my comment)? I seem to have overlooked/missed that. And yes, it seems we are in agreement,

Comment: As far as I know, finding a closed form solution for the number of paths between two points on a grid using NSEW moves is an open problem. @Andres Mejia, do you have information about this problem? I believe we've spoken about it before.

Answer (score 1):

The classic method for counting number of walks of length $L$ on a graph $G$ are to take the corresponding adjacency matrix $A$ and compute $A^L$.

No idea if this approach can be used to give a closed form etc solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[x^p]$ denote the coefficient of $x^p$ in a series $A(x)$.

> We consider lattice paths in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ of length $L$ from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ with steps in direction $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$.
>   The number of paths is given as:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^my^nt^L]}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-t\left(x+y+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)}}\\
> &=[x^my^n]\left(x+y+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)^L\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^my^n]\sum_{j=0}^L\binom{L}{j}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^j\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{L-j}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^L\binom{L}{j}[x^{m}]x^{-j}(1+x^2)^j[y^{n}]y^{-L+j}(1+y^2)^{L-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^L\binom{L}{j}[x^{m+j}](1+x^2)^j[y^{n+L-j}](1+y^2)^{L-j}\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{{j=0}\atop{{\,\,m\,\equiv\,j(2)}\atop{n+L\,\equiv\,j(2)}}}^L\binom{L}{j}\binom{j}{\frac{m+j}{2}}\binom{L-j}{\frac{n+L-j}{2}}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* and select the coefficient of $t^L$.
- In (2) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and do some rearrangements as preparation for the next step.
- In (4) we apply the rule $[z^{p+q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^{-q}A(z)$.
- In (5) we select the coefficients of $x^{m+j}$ and $y^{n+L-j}$.

> **Special case  $L=m+n$**
>
> We put $L=m+n$ and  obtain from (5)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{j=0}\atop{\,\,m\,\equiv\,j(2)}}^{m+n}&\binom{m+n}{j}\binom{j}{\frac{m+j}{2}}\binom{m+n-j}{n+\frac{m-j}{2}}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j\color{blue}{=m}}^{\color{blue}{m}}\binom{m+n}{j}\binom{j}{\frac{m+j}{2}}\binom{m+n-j}{n+\frac{m-j}{2}}\tag{7}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{m+n}{m}}
> \end{align*}
>   as expected.

*Comment:*

- In (6) we can skip one constraint since $n+L\equiv n+(n+m)\equiv m(2)$.
- In (7) we observe the middle binomial coefficient $\binom{j}{\frac{m+j}{2}}=0$ if $j<m$. We also note the right-hand binomial coefficient $\binom{m+n-j}{n+\frac{m-j}{2}}=0$ if $j>m$. We can therefore restrict the range of the index $j$ to $\{m\}$.

Comment: very straightforward and nice answer! (as usually yours are)

Comment: @GCab: Details added. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Total number of walks from of length L from Point `A` to `A` is given by

number of possible walks is $$\sum_{k=0}^{L/2}\frac{L!}{k!^2(L/2-k!)!^2}={L\choose L/2}\sum_{k=0}^{L/2}{L/2\choose k}^2={L\choose L/2}^2$$

Since you are calculating from point `A` to `B` , so shortest path will be of distance $:X =|A.x-B.X| ,  Y=|A.y-B.y| , S=X+Y$ , now just iterate towards the remaining length

$$\sum_{k=0}^{L-S}\frac{L!}{k/2!(L-S-k)/2!*(X+K/2)!*(Y+(L-S-k)/2)!} $$

Note: $K$ is incremented twice i.e $K=K+2$ and some base condition also $(L-S)$ should be even else there will be no path

Comment: Wow !! Beautiful

Comment: Can you please explain the formula it will be more clear :)

Comment: No !! not in mood

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

\begin{equation}
\binom{L}{\frac{L+n+m}{2}}\binom{L}{\frac{L+n-m}{2}}
\end{equation}

and can be found in [1].

In short, you set up a correspondence between NSEW-paths, $p$, and pairs $(p_1; p_2)$ of NS-paths. The $m$-th step of $p$ will correspond to the pair of $m$-th steps from $p_1$ and $p_2$ according to the following correspondence:

\begin{align}
p &\leftrightarrow (p_1,p_2)\\
-&-----\\
N &\leftrightarrow (N;N)\\
E &\leftrightarrow (N;S)\\
W &\leftrightarrow (S;N)\\
S &\leftrightarrow (S;S)
\end{align}

Then the NSEW-paths of $L$ steps from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m)$ are in one-to-one
correspondence with pairs $(p_1, p_2)$ of $L$-step NS-paths, where $p_1$ runs from
$(0,0)$ to $(0,n+m)$ and $p_2$ from $(0,0)$ to $(0, n-m)$. But the number of
NS-paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(0, k)$ of length $L$ is known [2, page 2] to be

\begin{equation}
\binom{L}{\frac{L+k}{2}},
\end{equation}

so the result follows by multiplying $\binom{L}{(L+n+m)/2}$ and $\binom{L}{(L+n-m)/2}$.

[1] Guy, Richard K., Christian Krattenthaler, and Bruce E. Sagan. "Lattice paths, reflections, & dimension-changing bijections." Ars Combinatorica. 1992.

[2] Mohanty, Gopal. Lattice path counting and applications. Academic Press, 1979.