# What is the probability distribution for manhattan distance on a finite grid?

Tags: probability, geometry

Suppose I have a finite grid of size NxN. (Example is in two dimensions).

I want to know whether there exists a closed-form formula (or approximation) for the probability distribution of the Manhattan distance between two randomly selected points, using the manhattan metric $$||a,b||_M = |x_a - x_b| + |y_a - y_b|$$.

So given two random points $a$ and $b$, what is $P(||a,b||_M = d)$ for any value $0 \leq d < 2N$?

By using a PRNG, and randomly trying out a billion points or so, the distribution looks like a parabola with a long tail. This is with $N = 256$:

[image: Example graph]

It's possible to manually enumerate the points... (given that $N > 3$).

$$d=0: \frac{N^2}{N^4} = \frac{1}{N^2}$$
$$d=2N-1: \frac{2}{N^4}$$
$$d=2N-2: \frac{8}{N^4}$$
$$d=2N-3: \frac{12 + 8}{N^4}$$

For $d=2N-1$ The points are in opposite corners.

For $d=2N-2$ observe that one point has to be in a corner, and the other point then has two possible locations.

For $d=2N-3$ there's a case with two pairs of points in opposite corners (four options, two symmetries), and one similar to previous case but with three options (three options, four symmetries).

This quickly balloons in possibilities though. I wonder if there's a better way of approaching this.

Comment: What is $M$? Perhaps it is $M=N$?

Comment: I would try to write a recursive function and work it out from there

Comment: This seems like it should be an easy/solved question, but apparently not. You probably already found https://amcm.pcz.pl/get.php?article=2005_1/art_06.pdf

Comment: Could you find the distribution for a single dimension and add the distributions (which would require assuming they are independent which they might be)

Comment: The distribution for a single dimension is `2-2x` but when I try constructing a 2-d PDF from this, it gives me a clearly wrong answer.

Comment: $
\begin{cases} \frac{2}{3} \left(c^3-6 c^2+6 c\right) & 0<c\leq 1 \\ -\frac{2}{3} \left(c^3-6 c^2+12 c-8\right) & 1<c<2 \end{cases}
$ is the pdf for the continuous version at c for 0 < c < 2. I got this by assuming the x and y distances were independent and integrating. This should really be a comment though because I'm not showing my work (I may edit later to do so)

Comment: @barrycarter The problem with that paper is everything from "it is easy to see that..." onwards. No, sorry, it is not easy to see. "Proof is left as an exercise to the reader" still leaves me stumped as to why it works. What is J? Why is one segment A-A and another B-B? How are you not double-counting (or missing) segments? I can see that the formula at least matches very closely, but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: The answer I give below is correct for the continuous version and you should be able to use it to approximate the discrete case, but let me know if not?

Comment: @aphid The "A-A" and "B-B" are in there because one needs to separate the cases where $1 \leq d \leq (n - 1)$ and $n \leq d \leq 2 (n - 1)$.  I'll delete my current answer and add in what I hope will be a better explanation.

Comment: Are the random selected points on the grid (discrete coordinates)? and is the grid unitarily spaced in $ [0,N]^2$? and the points uniformly and independently distributed in x,y ?

Comment: @G Cab: Yes to all three questions. The distribution is uniform.

Comment: @GCab Maybe I’m not understanding but what you say with $[0,N]^2$ would incorrectly make it a $(N+1)x(N+1)$ grid?

Comment: Maybe count paths of length $d$, then you should obtain what you are looking for by weighing them correctly. Maybe you find an inspiration here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400943/find-the-total-number-of-path-of-length-l

Comment: My Java program that computes this statistics by brute force by summation over all grid points is in https://vixra.org/abs/2306.0081